# Keeping user logged in across page refreshes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using Angular and Rails, and for authentication I'm using the [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) module with the [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gem.

For some reason, whenever I refresh the page, Angular "forgets" that the user is logged in.

The `auth_headers` cookie is getting set, although I don't know if it's getting set properly or not.

When the user is originally authenticated, Rails seems to be sending back a valid token.

I'm at a loss. Any troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am having this same problem right now.

Comment: This was a couple years ago and I don't remember, sorry. Maybe this [tutorial I wrote](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/authentication-with-angularjs-and-ruby-on-rails) will help.

Comment: That's the tutorial I was following, actually. That also didn't work for me :(